# EntityFramework : Unable to include nested member in LINQ join query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to execute a LINQ to Entity query which involves nested members. Below is the Entity schema. I'm keeping the code to a minimum for brevity.

```
public class NAVSummary
{
    public virtual IList<NAVStatus> Statuses { get; set; }
}

public class NAVStatus
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("NAVSummary")]
    public string Portfolio { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("NAVSummary")]
    public DateTime ValueDate { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual NAVSummary NAVSummary { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StatusId")]
    public NAVStatusMaster StatusMaster { get; set; }
}

[Table("NAVRec_StatusMaster")]
public class NAVStatusMaster
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext has DbSet's for all the above Entity's.

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var navSummariesTemp = dbContext.NAVSummaries
                            .Include(n => n.Statuses)
                            .Include(n => n.Comments)
                            .Include(n => n.Statuses.Select(s => s.StatusMaster))
                            .Include(n => n.Extracts)

                            .Join(dbContext.NAVSummaries,
                            current => new
                            {
                                current.Portfolio,
                                PD = SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", current.ValueDate) == 2 ? DbFunctions.AddDays(current.ValueDate, -3).Value :
                                        SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", current.ValueDate) == 1 ? DbFunctions.AddDays(current.ValueDate, -2).Value :
                                                                                            DbFunctions.AddDays(current.ValueDate, -1).Value
                            },
                            previous => new { previous.Portfolio, PD = previous.ValueDate },
                                                (outer, inner) => new { outer, inner })
                            .Where(w => w.outer.Statuses.Count > 0)
                            .Select(s => new
                            {
                                DayOverDayChange = s.outer.DifferencePercent - s.inner.DifferencePercent,
                                IsChange = s.inner.DifferencePercent == s.outer.DifferencePercent ? false : true,
                                Statuses = s.outer.Statuses
                            }).Take(10).ToList();
```

The above query yields everything except the NAVStatus.StatusMaster property. Although I have included the property at the start of the query using the Include() extension, the **public NAVStatusMaster StatusMaster { get; set; }** is still *null*.

However, when I execute the below query, the StatusMaster field does get set from the database record.

```
var statusResult = dbContext.NAVSummaries
                    .Include(n => n.Statuses)
                    .Include(n => n.Comments)
                    .Include(n => n.Statuses.Select(s => s.StatusMaster))
                    .Include(n => n.Extracts)
                    .Where(n => n.Statuses.Count > 0).First();
```

Really appreciate if someone could help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Eager loading only works on the last part of the query. If you use projection after the includes, everything is silently lost. The only solution to your problem is to specifically put the `StatusMaster` inside your projection:

```
.Select(s => new
{
   DayOverDayChange = s.outer.DifferencePercent - s.inner.DifferencePercent,
   IsChange = s.inner.DifferencePercent == s.outer.DifferencePercent ? false : true,
   Statuses = s.outer.Statuses,
   Statusmaster = s.outer.Statuses.SelectMany(s => s.StatusMaster)
                        }).Take(10).ToList();
```

However I don't think you really want the `StatusMaster` to be a separate list. Perhaps it would work to do your include at the end inside the select:

```
.Select(s => new
{
   DayOverDayChange = s.outer.DifferencePercent - s.inner.DifferencePercent,
   IsChange = s.inner.DifferencePercent == s.outer.DifferencePercent ? false : true,
   Statuses = s.outer.Statuses.Include(s => s.StatusMaster),
                        }).Take(10).ToList();
```

I'm not sure this will work though and can't test it as I have to go be somewhere :) The best option would be in my opinion to just make the `StatusMaster` virtual to enable lazy loading.

([See this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20100718113048/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/347543/entity-framework-eager-loading-not-working-in-some-projection-scenarios))